# How to create step template in octopus deploy to copy a file from package to Databricks cluster

Tags: databricks, artifactory, azure-databricks, octopus-deploy, octopus

I use Artifactory to publish NuGet packages. Package would have a file in publish folder which I should copy to Databricks cluster using Octopus deploy but can't seems to find a way to create step template

If I use deploy package step I can copy files/folder to target and read file like below

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "#{DATABRICKS_WORKING_DIRECTORY}" -Recurse -Filter *.whl | ForEach-Object  {
    $_.fullname
    #code to push file to databricks
}
```

Above approach might work but doesn't seems to be best approach, it would have been nice if I can create step template to push the file, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DataBricks, however, I did a little research and I think you could create a template using the Run a Script task as the base template.  Add a Package Parameter for the file that contains the `.whl` file, then use https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/libraries.html#install to upload it to DataBricks.  Does that help?

Comment: Run a script is something I tried but I have dependenacy on the package which should be downloaded and extracted on the target server before I could be copied, are you suggesting download and extraction also inside the script?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The Run a Script Task can be run on a worker (https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/workers) instead of a target.  In this case, the package would be extracted on the worker, then can be uploaded to DataBricks.